# Python - Mode Imputation - Apply mode for one column on another

Tags: python, pivot-table, imputation

I need required imputation in Python:

[image]

I tried using:

```
 # Outlet_Size - Imputation - Its Not Running need to check Version 2.X
    #Import mode function:
    from scipy.stats import mode

    #Determing the mode for each
    outlet_size_mode = data.pivot_table(values='Outlet_Size',
columns='Outlet_Type',aggfunc=(lambda x:mode(x).mode[0]))
```

but I'm facing error while creating pivot table itself, I'm using Python 3.X latest version.

Looking for other options also?

Comment: What error are you facing? Please read [ask] and provide as much *relevant* information as possible. You should also give your input data in text form so others willing to help can easily copy your data and the relevant part of your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) and for select first value add [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
outlet_size_mode = data.pivot_table(values='Outlet_Size',
                                   columns='Outlet_Type',
                                   aggfunc=lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
print (outlet_size_mode)
Outlet_Type Supermarket_Type2 Supermarket_Typel
Outlet_Size             Small            Medium
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , could you please elaborate on this i tried using that by still throws error..

Comment: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 1

Comment: t1.pivot_table(values='Outlet_Size',columns='Outlet_Type',aggfunc=lambda x: x.mode())

Comment: Are you sure? ` ✓` character is not green.

Comment: Click on the check mark (`✓`) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.